# Random Number Seed 4321 SPSS

Tags: random, spss, random-seed

I have a question where I need to use a random number seed 4321 to create a random sample with a normal distribution on SPSS. Does this just mean that I need to use the RV.NORMAL like usual or is seed 4321 something different?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need to specify a seed unless you want to produce the exact same "random" numbers in the future

Comment: Thank you - this was exactly the answer I needed! :)